# After I create my code, how do I give it a database?

Tags: javascript, html, css, database

I'd say I know how to code fairly well.
I've made 2 recent successful programs for work from using just javascript and html.
But I only know how to create them to where every program I make and share have individual copies.
There's no single database that I can edit the code and in result, subsequently all of my coworkers copies update as well.
Instead, any time I make changes to a program, I have to email them all the updated versions and have them update the programs on their computers.
What's my next steps to making all copies of my programs be manipulated by one database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to version your code the old fashion way, that means, every time you change something in your code, you create a copy and then send to your co-workers.

You don't need a database for that, instead, you should use `version control` like `git` or `svn`.

There are some serivces like

- [github](https://github.com/)
- [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org)
- [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)

where you can store your projects **private** or **public**, then give access to your colleagues, and they can also modify the code if you wish.